# Oracle Advanced Queues - missing messages and best approach to debug

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, advanced-queuing

Env: Oracle 12c

I currently have an Oracle Advanced Queue system setup as follows:

```
NAME                  QUEUE_TABLE     QID       QUEUE_TYPE      MAX_RETRIES  RETRY_DELAY  RETENTION
---------------       --------------- -------   --------------- -----------  -----------  ---------
MY_WORK_Q             MY_WORK_QT      2518333   NORMAL_QUEUE    100          0            0 
MY_WORK_QT_E          MY_WORK_QT      2518332   EXCEPTION_QUEUE 0            0            0
```

I also have registered a callback that calls a PL/SQL package procedure.

For some reason, I seem to have a situation where I am losing messages or messages are not being dequeued.

Based on this, I have the following questions:

1. Have I setup my actual queue - MY_WORK_Q with MAX_RETRIES and other info correctly?
2. Is there a way to check messages that have been enqueued?
3. Is there a way to check messages that have been de-queued?
4. Is there a means of checking the EXCEPTION_QUEUE/Exception table to see if lost messages have reached there?

I just can't see why I am losing messages within my queueing system and what I could check to see what might be causing the issue.

I also increased my MAX_RETRIES to 100 but still seem to be having issues.

### Update

It seems like I am getting the `error ORA-25263: no message in queue`.

I am not sure if this is related to a timing issue on the dbms_aq.enqueue or dbms_aq.dequeue calls but on the dbms_aq.dequeue I have this set:

```
l_dequeue_options.wait := dbms_aq.no_wait;
```

Do I require say a 10 second wait instead of no_wait? I am unsure if this possible and whether the wait needs to be on the enqueue or dequeue steps.

Comment: are there any records in the queue tables?

Comment: @OldProgrammer - actually, there are. I should've pointed out in my thread that I am new to AQs so really keen to figure out why these messages are being missed. Is there anything specifically I need to check within this table? What the reason might be, why there are still in this table?

Comment: @OldProgrammer - just noticed that these messages in the queue table were from 10 days ago and not during my testing today.

Comment: do you have access to oracle support?  If yes, look at KB article 233099.1 - "Master Note for Troubleshooting Advanced Queuing"  If not, I have the PDF but not sure how to get to you

Comment: to throw in about the question 3, you can change the retention time to a number different than 0 and the message will still visible in the queue table for that number of seconds configured. That would allow you to investigate if the message was there at all. However, depending on the messages volumes, enabling this can have it's drawbacks so better to not have that set up for production system with huge number of messages flowing through the queue

Comment: @OldProgrammer - it seems like I am getting the error ORA-25263: no message in queue. I am not sure if this is related to a timing issue on the `dbms_aq.enqueue` or `dbms_aq.dequeue` but on the `dbms_aq.dequeue` I have this set `l_dequeue_options.wait := dbms_aq.no_wait;` Does this perhaps need some type of wait?

Comment: `l_dequeue_options.wait` is a dequeue specific option. A wait > 0 means that a dequeue session would wait on an empty queue for those many seconds. If the queue is filled (enqueued) with messages within that period, a waiting dequeue session will fetch the message and return.

Comment: Please query queue table view `AQ$MY_WORK_QT` to see if the messages are indeed available for dequeue. A `msg_state` column with value = 'READY' mean that the messages are available for dequeue. msg_state = 'PROCESSED' means that a message has been dequeued. msg_state = 'EXPIRED' means that the message has been expired due maximum failed dequeue attempts. Expired messages are moved to an exception queue MY_WORK_QT_E.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that works.  Perhaps you can use it to identify your issue?

```
-- DROP TYPE some_type_t FORCE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE some_type_t AS OBJECT (
  a NUMBER,
  b VARCHAR(100),
  c DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE some_type_callback(CONTEXT  IN RAW,
                                               reginfo  IN sys.aq$_reg_info,
                                               descr    IN sys.aq$_descriptor,
                                               payload  IN RAW,
                                               payloadl IN NUMBER) AS

  -- Local variables
  v_dequeue_options    dbms_aq.dequeue_options_t;
  v_message_properties dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
  v_message_handle     RAW(26);
  v_some_type          some_type_t;
BEGIN

  -- Set the dequeue options from the descriptor
  v_dequeue_options.consumer_name := descr.consumer_name;
  v_dequeue_options.msgid         := descr.msg_id;

  -- Dequeue the message
  dbms_aq.dequeue(queue_name         => descr.queue_name,
                  dequeue_options    => v_dequeue_options,
                  message_properties => v_message_properties,
                  payload            => v_some_type,
                  msgid              => v_message_handle);
END some_type_callback;
/

SELECT *
  FROM user_errors e
 WHERE e.name = 'SOME_TYPE_CALLBACK';

BEGIN
 -- dbms_aqadm.drop_queue_table(queue_table => 'some_type_qt',
 --                             force       => TRUE);

  dbms_aqadm.create_queue_table(queue_table        => 'some_type_qt',
                                queue_payload_type => 'some_type_t',
                                multiple_consumers => TRUE);

  dbms_aqadm.create_queue(queue_name     => 'some_type_q',
                          queue_table    => 'some_type_qt',
                          retention_time => 86400); -- 1 day

  dbms_aqadm.start_queue(queue_name => 'some_type_q');

  dbms_aqadm.add_subscriber(queue_name => 'some_type_q',
                            subscriber => sys.aq$_agent(NAME     => 'some_type_qs',
                                                        address  => NULL,
                                                        protocol => NULL));

  dbms_aq.register(sys.aq$_reg_info_list(sys.aq$_reg_info('some_type_q:some_type_qs',
                                                          dbms_aq.namespace_aq,
                                                          'plsql://some_type_callback',
                                                          hextoraw('FF'))),
                   1);
END;
/

SELECT *
  FROM aq$some_type_qt;
-- nothing

DECLARE
  v_some_type some_type_t;
  eopt        dbms_aq.enqueue_options_t;
  mprop       dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
  enq_msgid   RAW(16);
BEGIN
  v_some_type := some_type_t(a => 42,
                             b => 'forty-two',
                             c => to_date('1/1/2942',
                                          'mm/dd/yyyy'));

  dbms_aq.enqueue(queue_name         => 'some_type_q',
                  enqueue_options    => eopt,
                  message_properties => mprop,
                  payload            => v_some_type,
                  msgid              => enq_msgid);
END;
/

SELECT *
  FROM aq$some_type_qt;
-- msg_state = READY => PROCESSED
```

One thing that will definitely help you is setting retention_time on your queue table.  You can then use the aq$ reference for the queue table to look at the messages.  The msg_state column will show READY for a fresh message and PROCESSED for a message that was consumed.  There are some other columns on there that can be helpful: retry_count for example.

If you are getting ORA-25263 it seems instead of handling the one message you are getting provoked for in your callback that you are trying to read a different message and clashing with another job that was started to consume the queue.  This is resolved by the two lines I have in my callback before calling dequeue.

If you need to trigger when a message arrives and then preserve message order you need to add some locking and additional complexity to your callback.  You could take a look at Metalink 225810.1 for examples on how to do this.